# How to add/change property in redux state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

```
    export default function() {
  return [
    {
      id: 1,
      author: "notCurrentUser",
      price: "200$",
      type: "Phone",
      name: "Redmi 8a",
      img: "https://i01.appmifile.com/webfile/globalimg/gaoruijia/Phone/C3K-red.png",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      author: "notCurrentUser",
      price: "350$",
      type: "Phone",
      name: "Note 10",
      img: "https://www.sunrise.ch/en/kmu/geraete/handys/samsung-galaxy-note10-plus-5g.primaryproductimage.code-MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDIwMDAx.format-hardware-configurator-l.png",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      author: "notCurrentUser",
      price: "1000$",
      type: "Phone",
      name: "IPhone XS",
      img: "https://mimelon.com/uploads/catalog/Product//iphone-xs-max-space-select-2018.png",
    },
]
}
```

So, i want to add new property into active product's object.
For example: I press at an IPhone XS and when i press, redux add new prop BASKET: TRUE, to IPhone XS's object. Like that:

```
{
          id: 3,
          author: "notCurrentUser",
          price: "1000$",
          type: "Phone",
          BASKET: TRUE,
          name: "IPhone XS",
          img: "https://mimelon.com/uploads/catalog/Product//iphone-xs-max-space-select-2018.png",
        },
```

I think, i can do something like that, but I am not sure:

```
 switch (action.type) {
        case  types.BASKET:
            return {
                action.payload,
                {
                 BASKET: TRUE
                }
            };        

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your component is something like below and there's some button that dispatches the action to add **Basket** attribute to the product **iPhone XS** therefore *name* is sent along.

Component.js:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const Component = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   return (
     <div onClick={()=>dispatch(addToBasket('IPhone XS')}></div>
   )
}
```

actions.js:

```
export const addToBasket = (name) = dispatch => {
 dispatch({ type: BASKET, payload: name });
}
```

reducers.js:

```
const defaultState = {
  products: [{
  id: 1,
  author: "notCurrentUser",
  price: "200$",
  type: "Phone",
  name: "Redmi 8a",
  img: "https://i01.appmifile.com/webfile/globalimg/gaoruijia/Phone/C3K-red.png",
},
{
  id: 2,
  author: "notCurrentUser",
  price: "350$",
  type: "Phone",
  name: "Note 10",
  img: "https://www.sunrise.ch/en/kmu/geraete/handys/samsung-galaxy-note10-plus-5g.primaryproductimage.code-MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDIwMDAx.format-hardware-configurator-l.png",
},
{
  id: 3,
  author: "notCurrentUser",
  price: "1000$",
  type: "Phone",
  name: "IPhone XS",
  img: "https://mimelon.com/uploads/catalog/Product//iphone-xs-max-space-select-2018.png",
}]
};

export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.BASKET: {
     let productToUpdate = state.products.find(item => item.name === action.payload);
     productToUpdate = { ...productToUpdate, BASKET: true }
     let products = state.products.filter(item => item.name !== productToUpdate.name);
    return { ...state, products : [...state.products, productToUpdate] } 
}
```

In the reducers file:

1. We are simply finding the particular product which needs to be updated by finding the product with the name 'IPhone XS'.
2. We add the attribute `BASKET: true` to the product.
3. Update the overall list of products by eliminating the previous product and adding this updated product to the list.

**Note**: *I would suggest you to update the product on the basis of id and not on the basis of name attribute as there can be multiple products with the name 'IPhone XS'.*